# Android AppwidgetProvider never called

Tags: android, widget

I'm following this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html tutorial.

Heres my Widetprovider:

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.asco.countdown.R;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context context) {
      Log.d("WID", "enabled");
  }



  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

      Log.d("WID", "update");

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
      // Create some random data
      int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget);
      Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
      // Set the text
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, String.valueOf(number));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
  }
}
```

Heres my widgetinfo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5000000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

and heres my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />  
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The widget is displayed, but neither the onEnabled() nor the onUpdate() methods are called, the onClickListener doesnt work either. 
I played around with giving the full path to the AppWidgetProvider in the manifest, putting the AppWidgetProvider in another package (right now its in the default package) and so on, but nothing happens, and now I'm out of ideas. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving full name in the maifest

```
<receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
```

to

```
<receiver android:name="com.asco.countdown.MyWidgetProvider" >
```

or what ever the full name

Comment: Try clean the project and run the application again. Hope you are studying Widgets based on web tutorial...last day i came accross the same tutorial and by doing these kind of stuffs, it got corrected.

Comment: Try changing the line : android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
to android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"

Comment: Tried cleaning and all, didnt help.
@Eldhose, the layout file is calles widget.xml so that should be alright. 

Another strange thing is: when I uninstall the widget from adb, the widget stays on the homescreen. Confusing.

Comment: Have you tried the above mentioned change?                                                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3000" >

</appwidget-provider>

Comment: Yes. But the layout is not the problem i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, tested it on a 4.0.3 emulator and 2.3 device, both worked fine. Seems to be a problem with my custom 4.1 JB rom.